# Pantheios : Separate logs per thread

Tags: c++, logging, pantheios

I'm making a multiple-thread program and I want to monitor each threads process using Pantheios.

Since each thread has lots of things going on, I need to separate the logs for each threads. (if not, the log file size would be monstrous)

Using the following function, I tried to separate the log files for each threads

```
    void threadClass::prepareLog()
    {
         static int counter = 1;
         CString strPath = _T("");
         strPath.Format(_T("log%d.log"),counter++);
         pantheios_be_file_setFilePath(strPath, PANTHEIOS_BEID_LOCAL);
    }
```

But as the result, all the threads logs would only be recorded to the last thread's log file.

I am still searching, but I wonder if Pantheios itself doesn't support multiple log files generation.

By the way, I am using Unicode character set.

If there is anything unclear or if there is any question, feel free to ask.

Thank you for your attention.